# Looking for contacts that are Pending (status by email) E-news Opt-in

Tags: email, groups, status, pending

We are having an issue with the number of bots that are signing up for our e-news online. I would like to search for all contacts that have a status pending by email to our E-news group.

Comment: What CMS are you using?

Comment: I am using Civi CRM 5.6.1

Answer (score 4):

[**Jon from Megaphone Tech**](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/users/12/jon-g-megaphone-tech) created a [**custom report**](https://github.com/MegaphoneJon/org.cpehn.subscriptionhistory) that that will allow you to filter by group status. Your system administrator would need to install it for you.

Comment: Thank you Tamar! However, I'm not the author of the report.  Thanks should go to Joseph Lacey. I only made the extension public.

Comment: After installing the above custom report, where should it appear in the menu? Although it appears to install successfully, it's not showing up under "Reports... All Reports" or anywhere else I've looked. I'm looking for "Subscription History".

Comment: Ugh... helps to read the README: "To use, go to Administer menu > CiviReport > Create New Report from Template, then select "SubscriptionHistory"."

Answer (score 1):

You can find Pending group members from Contacts > Manage Groups. Click "Contacts" for the desired Group. Then expand the "Find Contacts in Group" pane.

from this post https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php%3Ftopic=25642.0.html